# Install iOS 5.1.1 on iPod touch 4th gen not jailbroken with current iOS 4.1

Tags: itunes, ios, ipod-touch, software-update

I have an iPod 4<sup>th</sup> generation which is never jailbroken with iOS 4.1 and want to update it to 5.1.1. I downloaded the .ipsw file. On clicking <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + Restore in iTunes (10.7) and selecting the .ipsw file, I get the following error:

> This device isn't eligible for the requested build

I have tried editing the hosts file by adding a `#` in front of `74.208.10.249 gs.apple.com` but the error still persists. Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: You can’t do it now. That’s the honourable truth.

Comment: @duci9y why is it so..?

Comment: Apple only supports upgrading to the latest version at a time. For now, that is iOS 6.

Comment: @duci9y I can always use restore ipod and choose the ipsw file.

Comment: Nope. Every single restore and update ever is verified with Apple servers, or something else if you have set it up so.

Comment: I was about to ask this question myself. Thanks for the answer. I will give it a try (just for kicks) and if it is not possible, will upgrade to iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an iOS device is restored, it checks with Apple's servers to see if the version requested is still being "signed". If it is, the restore goes as planned. Right now, the only iOS version being signed by Apple is 6.1.3.

There is currently no way to restore to iOS 5.1.1 without being jailbroken in the past.

Answer (score 0):

What I have is an old 3g touch which has a maximum ios version of 5.1.1 and will never get any higher - they are pretty cheap on ebay - I can then use this for testing. If the device you buy has an older version of iOS it will be upgraded to a kosher 5.1.1 by iTunes.